# Is there a way to use traefik to route traffic to non dockerized web app

Tags: web, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have two web applications running on different ports and I want to use traefik to reverse proxy without dockerizing the web applications.  Is there a way this can be done?  Below is my attempt:

```
version: '3'
services:
  

  traefik:
    image: traefik:alpine
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.mysite.co.zw
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.enable=true

    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${PWD}/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - ${PWD}/acme.json:/acme.json
  
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080

  admin-web:
    ports:
      - '8300:8300'
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:admin.mysite.co.zw
      - traefik.port=8300
      - traefik.enable=true
    
  
  client-web:
    ports:
      - '8400:8400'
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:client.mysite.co.zw
      - traefik.port=8400
      - traefik.enable=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are not docker containers, they do not belong in the docker-compose file. You have to reference them in the a Traefik dynamic config file, as a service and router.

```
## DYNAMIC CONFIGURATION
http:
  services:
    srv-client-web:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - url: "http://yourinternalIP:8400"
    srv-admin-web:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - url: "http://yourinternalIP:8300"

  routers:
    rtr-client-web:
      entryPoints:
        - websecure
        rule: "Host(`client.mysite.co.zw`)"
        service: srv-client-web 
    rtr-admin-web:
      entryPoints:
        - websecure
        rule: "Host(`admin.mysite.co.zw`)"
        service: srv-admin-web
```

Apart from that:

- do NOT open up port 8080 for the Traefik dashboard on the internet, unless you put authentication middleware in between;
- do use Let's Encrypt certificates and only open up port 443 (it's 2021 after all);
- you need to have a static configuration file too, to put in your entrypoints, a reference to your dynamic config, certificate providers and the lot.